# Hide Unlicensed Account in Microsoft Teams Search - OnPremise Exchange

Tags: microsoft-office-365, exchange-2016, microsoft-teams

We have about 500 AD user accounts and 300 email mailboxes - 200 of which have a Teams account.
We are currently still using our on-premises Exchange 2016 server for all email accounts.
When searching for a user in Teams, the unlicensed accounts are also displayed.
Now there are plenty of tutorials and posts about how to limit this via customized Exchange Online address lists.
Unfortunately, all the posts only cover Exchange Online.
Does anyone have an idea how to solve this for on-premise environments as well?

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you're running a hybrid of Exchange 2016 and O365, I would say unfortunately the ABP/GAL is the idea. As Teams searches in your Azure Active Directory, the unlicensed users could also be searched. So you should enable the ABP for the Exchange online to narrow down the scope of searchable items in AAD.

But note if you deployed the ABP on those 200 who have Teams enabled, the other 100(if they are UNLICNESED) synced mailboxes could be disappeared from your address book.

Best regards